# WHERE inside SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Is it possible to do something like this in SQL?

```
SELECT SUM(jobRequirements.number) as total, 
    SUM(jobRequirements.number WHERE jobRequirements.type=1) as jobIT, 
    SUM(jobRequirements.number WHERE jobRequirements.type=2) as jobTourism FROM jobRequirements
```

I have inner joins here also with where clause but do I have to do separate queries with where clause for each `jobRequirements.type` or it can be done in one query?

My full query is from Laravel and it looks like this:

```
$jobStats = DB::table('jobRequirements')
            ->join('jobs', 'jobRequirements.job', '=', 'jobs.id')
            ->join('types', 'jobRequirements.type', '=', 'types.id')
            ->join('users', 'jobs.user', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('SUM(jobRequirements.number) as total, users.name'))
            ->where('jobRequirements.active', 1)
            ->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->get();
```

With this I get total number but I need to get sum of numbers by type.

**Update**

With this, a bit modified, code from @Terminus

```
SELECT SUM(jobReq.number) as total, users.name as user, types.name as type
FROM jobRequirements jobReq
INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id = jobReq.job
INNER JOIN types t ON t.id = jobReq.type
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = j.user
WHERE jobReq.active = 1
GROUP BY u.id, t.id
ORDER BY u.name ASC
```

I get this:

```
total  |  user  |  type
------------------------
2      |  user1 |  type2
5      |  user2 |  type6
1      |  user1 |  type3
3      |  user2 |  type2
```

What I need at the end is:

```
       | type2 | type3  | type6 | total
---------------------------------------
user1  | 2     | 1      | 0     | 3
user2  | 3     | 0      | 5     | 8
total  | 5     | 1      | 5     | 11
```

Comment: You are looking for `Case...When`

Comment: No idea how laravel works but can you just add another `group by` after the one you're doing on `users.id`? That would work in straight sql

Comment: No 2 where clauses in the same query is not possible, however you can nest queries ( sub-queries )

Comment: You're getting the total `number` already. Do you need to group that by the type as well?

Comment: And are there more than 2 types?

Comment: @Terminus yes there are more types.. I display it in table so now I have total number but I need to display it by type in type columns

Comment: So if the query got you the total number by type, you could get the grand total, no problem?

Comment: No, I don't have total number by type. I am trying to get that. All I have is grand total. Ignore that last number, I am not using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(jobRequirements.number) as total, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN jobRequirements.type=1 THEN jobRequirements.number ELSE 0 END) as jobIT, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN jobRequirements.type=2 THEN jobRequirements.number ELSE 0 END) as jobTourism 
FROM jobRequirements
```

Comment: I tried with `CASE WHEN jobRequirements.type=1 THEN SUM(jobRequirements.number) END as jobIT` but it still gives mi total number by all types in that case

Comment: What is your requirement in total, jobIT, jobTurism Column.

Comment: If you want sum by type then we could use partition.

Comment: I need sum of numbers that contain specific id for that columns

Answer (score 1):

Long answer, short:

Change the call to `groupBy` to this:

```
->groupBy('users.id', 'types.id')
```

Of course, now you'll start getting more rows returned per user.

---

Long answer, long:

So Laravel is probably building a query similar to the below one. (Note that `jobReq`, `j`, `t`, and `u` are what's called an alias which basically save you a bunch of typing)

```
SELECT SUM(jobReq.number) as total, users.name
FROM jobRequirements jobReq
INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id = jobReq.job
INNER JOIN types t ON t.id = jobReq.type
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = jobReq.user
WHERE jobReq.active = 1
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.name ASC
```

To order by `user.id` and by `type.id` you can add `t.id` to the `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT SUM(jobReq.number) as total, users.name
FROM jobRequirements jobReq
INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.id = jobReq.job
INNER JOIN types t ON t.id = jobReq.type
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = jobReq.user
WHERE jobReq.active = 1
GROUP BY u.id, t.id
ORDER BY u.name ASC
```

**New edit**

There's such a thing as a `PIVOT` command in SQL that can probably get you what you want but, i hate trying to write those statements. The simpler solution, in my inexpert opinion, is to loop over the results of the query, building an array to hold the data in a format you can loop over with a different loop as you display. Below:

```
$jobStats = DB::table('jobRequirements')
            ->join('jobs', 'jobRequirements.job', '=', 'jobs.id')
            ->join('types', 'jobRequirements.type', '=', 'types.id')
            ->join('users', 'jobs.user', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('users.name, types.id, SUM(jobRequirements.number) as total'))
            ->where('jobRequirements.active', 1)
            ->orderBy('users.name', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('types.id')
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->get();


// gather the values into an array
$displayJobStatus = array();
$allTypes = array();
foreach($jobStats as $stat) {
  if(array_search($stat['type'], $allTypes) === false) {
    $allTypes[] = $stat['type']; // we need to iterate over this later
  }
  $displayJobStatus[$stat['name']][$stat['type']] = $stat['type'];
}

$allTypes = sort($allTypes);

echo 'User Name | ' . implode(' | ', $allTypes) . ' | Total';
foreach($displayJobStatus as $userName => $typeTotals) {
  echo $userName . ' | ';
  $total = 0;
  foreach($allTypes as $type) {
    if(array_key_exists($type, $typeTotals)) {
      echo $typeTotals[$type] . ' | ';
      $total += $typeTotals[$type];
    }
  }
  echo $total . "\n";
}
```

you can turn the pipes (`|`) into html table tags pretty easy from here i think :)

Comment: this works fine but it is not suitable for my needs. I mean on display. Is it possible to set first column to users name and first row to types and then set number value to  proper place in table.. some kind of table matrix. Can this be done with sql or I need to code it in php?

Comment: @SpacePeasant please see edit. if that's not what you need, could you try mocking up some sample table data and then desired output and adding that to your question? (as a screenshot or as a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/))

Comment: I edited my question.. My main goal is probably beyond SQL and involves PHP but can I somehow make it easier with SQL?

Comment: there's ways and there's ways... the simplest solution is to take the results you're getting from my last query and loop over them, building an array you can loop over later to display the data you need.

Answer (score -2):

You cant use 2 where clauses in the same query

```
  SELECT SUM(jobRequirements.number) as total, 
jobRequirements.number WHERE jobRequirements.type=1 as jobIT, 
jobRequirements.number WHERE jobRequirements.type=2 as jobTourism FROM jobRequirements
```

You can however  ( just for example )

```
    SELECT
         (SELECT SUM(jobRequirements.number)) as total, 
          jobRequirements.number
    From
          jobRequirements WHERE jobRequirements.type=2
```

Tip, I don't know what any of ^ that means, really.  You can also do Unions :)  ( not Onions and not those guys with protest signs )